# Double dollar variable not being called correctly in a function

Tags: php

So, I have this code:

```
$str = '_POST';

print_r($$str);
//Works just fine

function request_var($name){
    global $_POST;
    $str = '_POST';
    print_r($$str);
}

request_var('username');
// _POST not defined
```

And what the request_var function was supposed to do was loop through the $_POST, $_GET, and $_COOKIE variables (in that order) and if it finds the passed variable name, stop looking and return that value.

I had a system awhile back that worked as intended, but for some reason now it tells me `_POST not defined` and I can't figure out why? The first part works without errors, but the second part doesn't work at all. Isn't $_POST a super global? (Note: I only added in the `global $_POST` to see if that would fix it)

Any ideas?

EDIT: Based on the answer provided by another user ( can't see their name in the edit screen), my work around is thus:

```
function request_var($name,$default='',$force_type=false){
        $end = $default;
        $arrays = [$_POST,$_GET,$_COOKIE];

        foreach($arrays as $array){
            if(isset($array[$name])){
                $end = $array[$name];
                break;
            }
        }

        return ($force_type) ? settype($end,gettype($default)) : $end;

    }

    echo request_var('username');
    //Works just fine
```

Comment: yes $_POST is super global http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: please do some  research before asking question you can see that duplicate has the exactly same issue and solve your question

Comment: I did, but "double dollar sign not working with post" didn't give any results other than the superglobals page, which i didn't read far enough down.

Comment: You could also have merely used `$GLOBALS[$str]` in lieu of `$$str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Warning**  Please note that variable variables cannot be used with PHP's Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods.

[source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: hmm. Will have to rethink code. Could have sworn i used this same syntax previously, but that was almost an entire version ago so, who knows. Thanks! edit: will accept answer as soon as it will let me

Comment: Just put the superglobals in an array outside of the function and use that instead.

Comment: Check my edit to the question, that's how I decided to go around it